# How to speed up Gitlab CI build process (not working)

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've searched the web to find out how to speed up my CI build time, I've implemented these methods but, every time I push code to gitlab it rebuilds the image from scratch (docker) without using any cache, even if nothing has changed.

**EDIT**
This is what my .gitlab-ci.yml file looks like:

```
# ### Define variables
#
variables:
 OBJECTS_DIRECTORY: 'obj'    
 NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY: '.nuget'
 SOURCE_CODE_PATH: 'src/'
 REACT_PATH: ClientApp
 DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2           

# ### Define stage list
stages:
 - build
 - push
 - test
 - deploy

cache:
 # Per-stage and per-branch caching.
  key: "$CI_JOB_STAGE-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG" 
  paths:
    - '$SOURCE_CODE_PATH$REACT_PATH/node_modules/'

build:
  image: docker:18.09
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:18.09-dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest || true
  script:
    - >
      docker build
      --pull
      --cache-from $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA

push latest:
  image: docker:18.09
  stage: push
  services:
    - docker:18.09-dind
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  only:
    - master
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - docker tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
```

This is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /source

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x |  bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs


COPY ./src/*.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

COPY ./src/ ./

RUN dotnet publish "./Spa.csproj" --output "./dist" --configuration Release --no-restore

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /source/dist .

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates \
    && curl -S https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg --output /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg \
    && echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list \
    && apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y php7.2-cli

COPY deployment.ini /app
ADD ./src/appsettings.Sample.json /app/appsettings.json

EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Spa.dll", "--environment=Production"]
```

Everything looks right, so I have no clue why it doesn't use cache on the build stage

Comment: Can you add links to the methods you used to speed up build time?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni This was the main link I followed https://blog.callr.tech/building-docker-images-with-gitlab-ci-best-practices/

Comment: You should remove parts of the pipeline definition that not relevant, making a more minimal example. Everything after the build stage I'd guess. Also post your `Dockerfile`. If for example you do something to bust the cache in the first command you will not see any speedups from cache.

Comment: @renefritze I added the Dockerfile, and left two stages (build, and push latest), push latest is essential to the cache process.

Comment: Did you time building with/without cache on your local machine. I somewhat expect you won't see much difference there either.

Comment: @renefritze on my local machine it actually uses the cache made by docker but it doesn't on gitlab. For example on my local machine when it it reaches `
RUN apt-get install -y php7.2-cli` it says loading from cache, but on gitlab the log shows it as downloading php7.2-cli